# How to convert an object type into json b type?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using an Api to get data and save it into my own PostGre Database. The data I received from API is in this structure: 
[image: unit_amount_in_cents.USD._ = 62]

So the unit_amount_in_cents is an object with a key, it is "USD" in this case, the value is another object which has a key name "_" and value of 62.

But I need to convert it into Json b type so I can save it into my database.

Please keep in mind for all the default values, it can be null for any of this keys and values or even the whole thing.

I have tried code like this:

```
return {unit_amount_in_cents: data.unit_amount_in_cents}
```

Also tried:

```
return {
   unit_amount_in_cents: {
       [Object.keys(data.unit_amount_in_cents)[0]] :  ((data.unit_amount_in_cents || {}).USD || {})._ || 0,
}
}
```

This works, but I feel like I am hard coding it.

Can someone provide me a better way?

Comment: Is the Java tag relevant here?

Comment: removed it. I think this is an overall programming question.

Comment: It's very specific to JavaScript - this would not even be applicable for some other languages and even if it is, they might have different facilities to deal with it. So, it's not a generic question, nor can it be answered generically.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the info, I glad I removed it.